# Symfony2 input radio in table

Tags: php, symfony

I've got a form template to respect and I haven't found the best way to create this with Symfony.

The final form renderer should be like this (input radio):

```
--------------------------------------
|   ○   |   Description 1   |   0 $  |
------------------------------------- 
|   ○   |   Description 2   |   10 $ |
--------------------------------------
|   ○   |   Description 3   |   50 $ |
--------------------------------------
|   ○   |   Description n   |   ...  |
--------------------------------------
```

So I've created a FormType class with a choice field, but just only one label is possible.

I've tried this:

```
$builder
    ->add('quantity', 'choice', array(
        'choices' => array(
            50   => array('desc' => 'Description 1', 'price' => 0),
            100  => array('desc' => 'Description 2', 'price' => 10),
            150  => array('desc' => 'Description 3', 'price' => 50),
            200  => array('desc' => 'Description 4', 'price' => 100),
        )
    )
;
```

But it doesn't work, Symfony creates two input by row ...

I also try with a ChoiceList, but i've the error "Array to string conversion error"...

Do you know what is the best way for to build this simple form interface ?

Answer (score 2):

As described in the [Choice field docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choices) to display radio fields using the `choices` field you need to change your field to (because it accepts only monodimensional arrays):

```
$builder
->add('quantity', 'choice', array(
    'expanded' => true,
    'multiple' => false,
    'choices'  => array(
        50   => 'what you want string',
        100  => 'what you want string',
        150  => 'what you want string',
        200  => 'what you want string',
    )
)
```

;

For more advanced needs you need to use `choice_list` option and use it accordingly to the [ChoiceListInterface](http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/ChoiceList/ChoiceListInterface.html) or [Build a Custom Field](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html)